# Does anyone hold that בֵּית לָחֶם is also a person's name?

Tags: sources-mekorot, names, geography, book-of-chronicles, micah

In [Divrei Hayamim I 4:4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t25a04.htm) Hur is listed as the father of בֵּית לָחֶם.

> אֵלֶּה בְנֵי-חוּר בְּכוֹר אֶפְרָתָה, אֲבִי בֵּית לָחֶם

The commentaries I have seen read this as he fathered people who lived in בֵּית לָחֶם. However that doesn't seem to be the plain meaning of the pasuk.

Furthermore in [Micha 5:1](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t1805.htm) the Navi speaks about בֵּית לָחֶם as if it were a person.

> וְאַתָּה בֵּית-לֶחֶם אֶפְרָתָה, צָעִיר לִהְיוֹת בְּאַלְפֵי יְהוּדָה--מִמְּךָ לִי יֵצֵא, לִהְיוֹת מוֹשֵׁל בְּיִשְׂרָאֵל; וּמוֹצָאֹתָיו מִקֶּדֶם, מִימֵי עוֹלָם

Are there any m'forshim who say that בֵּית לָחֶם is also used as the proper name of a person?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/22510/759

Answer (score -1):

Considering that the city was a well established fortification at 1400 BC, and was first built long before, it is unlikely that the text refers to a person, rather than the city.